# Android Java OpenGL ES 2.0 Loading text from external file not completing the texture

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

When loading from resources there is no issue, but using the same method with a bitmap loaded from a File object the texture is not conplete. The data is loading, the image shows correct, but when querying for a new texture name the previous one is always returned.

Developing on Android 4.2.2, OpenGL ES 2.0
[Code removed as it's no longer important.]

UPDATE: When it's all called prior to the first render it works, but then adding another texture falls back to the first name again. Like each render pass resets everything.

Final Update:

I figure out the issue, it had nothing to do with the texture, it was the context's lifecycle. In case anyone else runs into this, using an external acitivity in an OpenGL app can cause the OpenGL context to be lost. You have to reload everything when that happens. I didn't know the context was lost so easily in Android.

Comment: I don't see an immediate problem with the code you posted. Are you deleting textures in other parts of your code, with calls to `glDeleteTextures()`? Just to be extra safe, can you try and set `TEMP_ID[0] = 0` before the `glGenTextures()` call, and see if you actually get the same id again, or if for some reason it is not writing the id at all? I figure the `checkGlError()` test is active, and does not detect any errors? Where are you calling this function from? Sorry about all the questions, just trying to dig for possible issues.

Comment: Deleting only happens with user input, so that's not it. I tried the setting it to zero prior too, that didn't help. This is really perplexing. lol

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that setting it to zero could fix the problem. It's a diagnostic experiment. What's the value of `TEMP_ID[0]` after the `glGenTextures()` call if you set it to zero prior to the call?

Comment: Same thing, the texture is still not marked as complete. I get the first valid name, but then the next call it pulls the same name as the previous. I am starting to wonder if it's not a bug in the SDK APIs at this point. But the SDK limits access to a lot of OGL functions. Considering dropping to the NDK just because of tbis.

Comment: Oh, your context went away! Yes, that makes sense. Probably should have thought of that possibility, but it's always easier in hindsight... Can you post the solution as an answer? I think we can turn this into a generally useful question/answer because it's an interesting problem that others might encounter.

Comment: The site recommends to add the solution in the original post. But yeah, I spent three days looking at the wrong part of the program. lol I feel kinda stupid for not looking deeper. I don't know how to mark it as solved either.